# xCode 7: how to fix initialization of variable was never used consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

Tags: xcode, swift

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "isDone", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) }
```

the `var alert` and `let okAction` are error, the error message below
"initialization of variable was never used consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it"

I can't find the error, please help me to fix this error. Thank you!

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is telling you that you are not using the constants you created.

This is a useful warning because creating a constant an never reading indicates a possible mistake in the code.

So... just use them adding this line

```
alert.addAction(okAction)
```