# Initialization of variable was never used

Tags: swift, var

[image]

I am new to Swift. I am trying to do a little project. I got this warning on `var`:

```
Initialization of variable was never used consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it.
```

If anyone could help me, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xCode 7: how to fix initialization of variable was never used consider replacing with assignment to '\_' or removing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390868/xcode-7-how-to-fix-initialization-of-variable-was-never-used-consider-replacing)

Comment: Please do not paste images of text like that. It's very hard to work with, and people are less likely to respond to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use this variables later - just ignore this warnings.

But didn't you mean something like this?

```
var allText = ""
var firstLetter = ""
var firstSentence = ""
var body = ""
var info = ""
var map = ""
var about = ""

func changeNameToIndex(index: Int) {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        allText = "..."
        firstLetter = "..."
        // etc
    case 1:
        allText = "..."
        firstLetter = "..."
        // etc
    case 2:
    // ....
    default:
    // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I did that but I got the warnings and I thought that I did something wrong. I plan to use them later so I ignore the warnings. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `let` if the variable is not mutable and use `_` if the variable is not going to use anywhere else which means if the variable is not using then no need to give a name to it so that you can replace them with `_`

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270732/what-do-and-in-mean-in-swift-programming-language) on SO

Use it by making the variable outside the switch statement begins because you are using the same variable name in all the other case

```
var name = ""
switch index
{
    case 0:
        name = "English"
    case 1:
        name = "Spanish"
    default:
        name = "Default"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**var** is used in case you know that the variable you are declaring will be used in future in the class.

**let** is used in case you know that the variable will not be mutated/changed/updated in the class

If you know that the variable will neither be used not mutated then consider using _ . An **_ parameter** will be explicitly ignored & can not be used anywhere in the class/function

if you declare a variable using let and try to change or update its value, you will get a warning to change it to var type.